c# Validate Certification Authority not present in Trusted Root Certification Auth on WCF service
I need to make an SSL connection to a soap service.
The problem is that the ROOT CA that must validate the certificate from the server cannot be present on the System Root Trust Store of the client. It must be loaded at runtime.
The final implementation is under Linux but it doesn't work on windows as well.
It works only if I add the Root CA in the system CA. In the other cases I receive always an exception.
The Root CA has not dependencies from other CA. It is a stand alone Certificate.
I'm using .net core 6
The class UserManagemenClient is autogenerated.
public partial class UserManagementClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ConsoleApp7.UserManagementService.IUserManagement>, ConsoleApp7.UserManagementService.IUserManagement


Navigating on internet seems that the solution is implement a custom certification validator, but, running the program, it's never called.
The program raise the below exception.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'gui.net:8443'.)
 ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'gui.net:8443'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthenticationWithTelemetryAsync(Boolean isAsync, Boolean isApm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Here below the sample used
    public void Test2(string url)
    {

        var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None)
        {
            Name = "UserManagementServiceSoapBinding"
        };
        httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        httpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
        if (uri.ToLower().Contains("https"))
            httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri);

        var client = new UserManagementClient(httpBinding, endpointAddress);

        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomRootCertificateValidator(rootCaCertPath);

        try
        {
            var result = client.checkOTPAsync("aaa", new[]
            {
                "", "", ""
            }).Result;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Worked");

    }
}


public class CustomRootCertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
    private X509Certificate2 _rootCertificate;

    public CustomRootCertificateValidator(string rootCertificatePath)
    {
        _rootCertificate = new X509Certificate2(rootCertificatePath);
    }

    public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(certificate));
        }

        var chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(_rootCertificate);
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        bool isValid = chain.Build(certificate);
        if (!isValid || chain.ChainElements[^1].Certificate.Thumbprint != _rootCertificate.Thumbprint)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("La validazione del certificato è fallita. Il certificato radice non è attendibile.");
        }
    }
}

Any idea?

Try modifying client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
to client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.custom; At the same time, it is not practical to skip certificate validation on asp.net core. Its security is high, and any attempt to skip is not allowed.

I tried also this scenario but i receive the same issue.
